# ExpandableListView custom design

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, android-custom-view, custom-view

I want customize ExpandableListView, but I can't get to customize childs. How can I make a border and fill the background (example below src code)

What I have:

[image]

**ExpandableListView**

```xml
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expListviewServices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:childDivider="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**list_fragment_services_groups.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/expandblelistview_background"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgServicesGroup"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_internet" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtServicesGroup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgServicesGroup"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_fragment_services_child.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtServicesChild"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**expandblelistview_background.xml**

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/lightgray" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

What I want:

[image]

**ADD:**

```java
public class ServicesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = ServicesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> group;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> child;
    private Context context;

    private static String GROUP_NAME = "group_name";
    private static String GROUP_IMAGE = "group_image";
    private static String CHILD_NAME = "child_name";

    public ServicesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> group, ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> child) {
        this.context = context;
        this.group = group;
        this.child = child;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return group.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return group.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_services_groups, null);
        }

        if (isExpanded) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expandblelistview_background_selected);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expandblelistview_background);
        }

        ImageView imgServicesGroup = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgServicesGroup);
        TextView txtServicesGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtServicesGroup);

        txtServicesGroup.setText(group.get(groupPosition).get(GROUP_NAME));
        int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_" + group.get(groupPosition).get(GROUP_IMAGE), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imgServicesGroup.setImageResource(imageId);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_fragment_services_child, null);
        }

        TextView txtServicesChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtServicesChild);
        txtServicesChild.setText(child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get(CHILD_NAME));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Adapter's code?

Comment: You can style the children `View`s in the `getChildView()` method.

Comment: @MarkBuikema I know about this, but I thought there is a simpler way for customization

Comment: To get the border, you can check if the view is the last child, by `if (getChildCount() - 1 == childPosition)`. If this is true you can change the background to the bottom border

Comment: @MarkBuikema Thank you, I always done this buy adding some drawables and this check